# Azure Web Role in Azure Virtual Network can't access SQL Azure in same region (West US)

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles, webrole, azure-virtual-network

I have a Web Role that needs access to a SQL Server on premise as well as a SQL Azure, hence we created an Azure Virtual Network for a Site-to-Site connection.

I have a few outstanding issues:

1. The web role is only able to access the SQL Azure by IP.  Both are in the same region, the Role is in the Virtual Network.
2. I have to remove Encrypt=true from the connection string to SQL Azure to avoid getting a certificate chain error.

This was not a problem before when the Web Role was not in a Virtual Network.  It was able to connect to the on premise database via Azure Connect, however, that product is being phased out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rafi